# How to close the program by pressing button?

Tags: python, linux, button, tkinter

I hope you can help me with this problem..

I have the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time

def start():
    start_stop.config(text="QUIT", command=stop)
    for i in xrange(5):
        pbar_det.step(19.99)
        master.update()
        # Busy-wait
        time.sleep(1)
    master.quit()

def stop():
    master.quit()

master = Tk()

start_stop = Button(master, text='START', command=start)
start_stop.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=600, mode="determinate")
pbar_det.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

master.mainloop()
```

I press the start button and the progress bar starts, the button text changes to "QUIT" and ends (and the program is closed) when the bar is full (five seconds)

How I can do so that pressing "QUIT" close the program at that time? (not waiting for the bar fills)

I hope you can help me!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time
import threading

def start():
    start_stop.config(text="QUIT", command=stop)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=progBar, args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def progBar():
    for i in xrange(5):
        pbar_det.step(19.99)
        master.update()
        # Busy-wait
        time.sleep(1)
    master.quit()

def stop():
    master.quit()

master = Tk()

start_stop = Button(master, text='START', command=start)
start_stop.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=600, mode="determinate")
pbar_det.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

master.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

Variable name fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but if the bar is full and the button is not pressed> the program is not completed within 5 seconds. Remains open until we press the "QUIT" button, as Fix it?

Comment: If I understand, you want the program to quit if the progress bar finishes as well.  It should work like that now.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I wanted @JpajiRajnish.
I solved adding: master.destroy() instead of master.quit()
Thanks!!

Comment: Good to hear.  If my answer worked for you you can check mark it to make it the accepted answer.  Take care.